# REST API that calls another REST API

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns

Is it proper programming practice/ software design to have a REST API call another REST API? If not what would be the recommended way of handling this scenario?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then **YES**, it is extremely common.

You are describing the following, I presume:

> Client makes API call to Server-1, which in the process of servicing
>   this request, makes another request to API Server-2, takes the
>   response from Server-2, does some reformatting or data extraction, and
>   packages that up to respond back the the Client?

This sort of thing happens all the time. The downside to it, is that unless the connection between Server-1 and Server-2 is very low latency (e.g. they are on the same network), and the bandwidth used is small, then the Client will have to wait quite a while for the response. Obviously there can be caching between the two back-end servers to help mitigate this.

It is pretty much the same as Server-1 making a SQL query to a database in order to answer the request.

An alternative interpretation of your question might be that the Client is asking Server-1 to queue an operation that Server-2 would pick up and execute asynchronously. This also is very common (it's how Google crawls your website, for instance). This scenario would have Server-1 respond to Client immediately without needing to wait for the results of the operation undertaken by Server-2. A message queue or database table is usually used as an intermediary between servers in this case.

Comment: How about if you are designing some API. Say you have method X and Y. Y calls X and then do something else? Is that a good practice? In my opinion, it's not. Client should call X, then call Y. And Y should not repeat what X did. But I couldn't find any written rule about it. Also, is there any case when it's ok to have Y calling X?

Comment: actually, found this to support my argument https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: @chepukha that depends on if X and Y are considered to be at the same "level" or not. it's ubiquitous for an API to call a lower-level API to get work done that is part of the necessary functioning of that API. Does Y depend on X? or is it ancillary?
take an `area()` API for example—it needs to call the `multiply()` API to perform its function. That does not violate SRP.